# Accessing dynamic database in laravel

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am working on an application. I have a master database, where I store all database names. I have made an api, which sends db_name. If that db_name exists in master db, it fetches that value and credentials.

After that, I want to perform all my operations on that new database.

I have written controller function like this, but it does not seem to work:

```
public function test(Request $request) {

    $users = Config::where('db_name', '=', $request->db_name)->first();

    if ($users) {
        config(['database.mongodb' => [
            'database' => $users->db_name
        ]]);
    }

    $contacts = \DB::collection('contacts')->get();

    return response()->json($contacts);

}
```

Url I am accessing : 
`http://localhost:8000/api/test?db_name=79b83e17125f770f0294619942586e57`

**api.php**
`Route::get('/test', 'SearchController@test');`

I am using mongodb, and jenssegers/laravel-mongodb library. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching and googling, I find out a solution which is working

https://lukevers.com/2015/03/25/on-the-fly-database-connections-with-laravel-5

Answer (score 0):

> you can get like that two way

```
public function test(Request $request) {

    $users = Config::where('db_name', '=', $request->db_name)->first();

    $contacts = \DB::collection($users->db_name.'.contacts')->get();

    return response()->json($contacts);
}
```

> also you can change database name run time into config file

```
  public function test(Request $request) {
        $users = Config::where('db_name', '=', $request->db_name)->first();

         if ($users) {
             \Config::set('database.connections.mongodb.database',$users->db_name);
          }
// retrun DB::connection()->getDatabaseName()
         $contacts = \DB::collection('contacts')->get();

         return response()->json($contacts);
}
```

Comment: Tried new solution too, but it's still giving empty results. I have one record in the database which I am passing in api

Comment: @ManojKumar i aded second way please try this

Comment: @ManojKumar  return DB::connection()->getDatabaseName(); make sure your connection after change.

Comment: It's not changing db name, it's returning null, after change.

Comment: For multiple connection, here docs talk about the connection mentioned in database.php manually. It's not the case in present scenario. After doing all this, I have checked it's not changing connection setting which are default in database.php